# Why isn't the time auto changing to the latest minute/hour?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm building a basic clock app for practice and for some reason the time isn't automatically changing to the latest minute or hour. Example, the current time is 17:56 but it is showing 17:54 which was the latest time I opened the app.

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *theOutput = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[theOutput setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSString *dateString = [theOutput stringFromDate:now];

NSString *time = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"The current time is %@", dateString];
[currentTime setText:time];
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to call this code every time you want the time. It won't update on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show sets the data and time to the time when that code executes. There's nothing in that code that would update the clock. Are you calling this code once every minute? If, not, you need to call it once a minute with an NSTimer.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `currentTime` variable is assigned. If yes, call:

```
[currentTime setNeedsDisplay];
```

after you set the text.